# How to get the ID value

Tags: jquery

```
$(function ()
{

    $(".tb").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "StudentName.asmx/FetchNameList",
                data: "{ 'FirstName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

                        return {
                            value: item.Name
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

i want to get the id field from above, i have created a new textbox  and inserted  $('.id').val(item.ID); but it doesnot return the same id field that i have select from the autocomplete textbox. How can i get that id?

JSON data that i'm getting is like this.

{"d":[{"_*type":"Student","ID":1,"Name":"Sagar  Khyaju"},{"*_type":"Student","ID":2,"Name":"Sagar  Khyaju"},{"__type":"Student","ID":4,"Name":"Sagar  Lkkk"}]}

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in case anyone needs it.  Cheers! :)

```
 $(function () {
        $(".tb").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "StudentName.asmx/FetchNameList",
                    data: "{ 'FirstName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Name, ID: item.ID
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                $(".student_id").val(ui.item.ID);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the jsondata in a variable and you can iterate from the result variable

```
var result= eval("(" + jsondata + ")");
```

I guess you are using auto complete

Please have a look at the below link

[Auto Complete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Comment: hey vipin thanks for your answer but i have already got the name from JSON all i want is the id field value with respect to the Name. For eg in above json if i select Sagar Lkkk i want ID=4.

Comment: @user948253 What type of control are you using